# Get site name config value in page.html.twig template

Tags: 8

Is there a way to get the site name config value as a variable in the page.html.twig template? I am only able to get null values when I try to get the value in the preprocess function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get site name in custom template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/192348/get-site-name-in-custom-template)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am only able to get null values when I try to get the value in the preprocess function.

Null values based on doing what exactly?

The site name, logo etc. was moved to a block, that's why it's no longer available out of the box. However, you can always add it back yourself and make it available in twig:

```
$variables['site_name'] = \Drupal::config('system.site')->get('name');
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you can also use the following technique with [twig_tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)

```
{{ drupal_config('system.site', 'name') }}
```